# Resampling and Aggregating Function as the Closing Value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

**Problem:**

Consider the population table from the below dataframe.I want to downsample the dataframe to decadal data, with population taking in the value of close of the decade. So for decade 1960-1970, the population will be that of 1970.

Consider it to be an "end of the period" population. How can I go about it?

**Context:**
Many variables in businesses/demographics are "stock" variables, i.e. they represent "beginning of period" value and "end of period" value. Thus they do not add up during downsampling, instead they can take the usual aggregations (except sum, like mean, median) or take the closing value.

[image]

Comment: Hi, why not simply drop years that are not 'decade' ones (1960, 1970, etc.) and rename index if needed?